# webdriverio - standalone selenium server Vs grid/hub

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid, webdriver-io

I have this in a `wdio.conf.js` file.

```
...
 specs: [
      './test/specs/mocha-test.js',

      './test/specs/mocha-test-po-copy.js'

    ],


    capabilities: [ {
        maxInstances: 2,
        browserName: 'firefox',

    }, 
   {
        maxInstances: 2,
        browserName: 'chrome',

    } 
    ],
....
```

when I run the above specs by using selenium grid/hub, and initializing node by keeping `maxInstances=4` all sessions opens up immidiately but if I keep `maxInstances` less than 4 for any of the two bowser while registering the node, only two instances start up at a time and third one starts only when one of the first two instances gets finished.

When I use standalone selenium server(without grid setup), all instances, starts immediately and close down one by one when they finish.

My question is what is the use of selenium grid then, it seems using standalone, it is opening all instances at once and hence faster results. Also,with grid, we have to always keep a check to register the node with `maxInstances=4`. Then why would one use grid?